# From where is this image of Nene Yashiro and Hanako-kun hugging?

Tags: toilet-bound-hanako-kun

This looks like a cropped image of Nene and Hanako hugging, but I don't know which chapter this is from.

[image]

I've tried using Pinterest obviously to find it but no one person has commented which chapter. I’ve also tried to reverse the image but the same thing shows up.

From which chapter is this image taken?

Answer (score 1):

**It's from the last page of chapter 67.**

Reverse-searching the image returned a link to [aminoapps.com](https://aminoapps.com/c/toiletbound/page/blog/gonene-manga-panel-coloring/8BdM_dMnHmujYgW2Rvj62LozPakoMq41gJN) which mentions "TBHK Chapter 67 Spoilers".

> [image]